# Regarding routing packets via one computer to another

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I am setting up packet routing via a host computer. In order to try out a simple case. I set up a small local network of 3 linux PCs X,Y,Z. These 3 get their IP from a DLink router that I have. X,Y, Z can ping each other.

I want to route packets coming from X to Z via Y.

This must not need NAT I guess.

But even getting this simple routing doesn't seem to work.

Here are more details:

X: 192.168.0.100
y:192.168.0.3
Z:192.168.0.7

When X sends packets addressed to Y, Y should forward them to Z.

What iptable rules should I use?

Is it enough if I just setup a route command alone?

I tried on Y after setting ip_forward=1:

route add -host 192.168.0.7 gw 192.168.0.3

But I don't achieve the result. Please advise.

Should I change something on my D-link router?

And oh btw the catch is I have to achieve this by not changing anything on system X as it is not under my control.

Thanks

Comment: How will Y know which packets it should forward to Z? And what layer are you trying to do this at? Is this NAT? Or proxying? Or what? (We could probably give you a much better answer if we knew what problem you were trying to solve.)

Comment: Y should forward tcp packets received on ports 9000 and 7000 to Z.

Comment: And should Z see them coming from Y so replies go back to Y? Or should Z them coming from X and send replies to X?

Comment: If system X is not under your control, do you actually have permission to hijack its IP traffic?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:Z should send it to Y which again forwards the replied back to X. This is just a small experiment. Eventually there will be another internal interface between Y and Z with a different subnet. But for now, I want this routing done..

Comment: @pjc50: Well of course I have control on X while this is just an experiment setup. But later I want any client communications to Z to be routed via Y and therefore I do not want to change some routing rules on X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two machines are on the same IP "network" and on the same ethernet network, they will route packets directly to one another. In order to change this you need to either:

- renumber Z, then set Y up as the gateway used by X
  OR
- put 2 ethernet cards in Y, configure it as an ethernet bridge.

Comment: Of course X can talk directly to Z but like I said, I am trying to have a simple forwarding setup here.

Comment: Yes, but the important thing is that you cannot *prevent* X talking directly to Z instead of through Y unless you change one of "same IP network" or "same ethernet segment".

Comment: what do u mean renumber Z?

Comment: COuld you please elaborate? I would like to try it. Y is a board and has only one eth interface.

Comment: Change Z to 192.168.1.7. Make sure that Y's interface has two addresses, 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.1.3. Tell X (or the dlink) that to route packets to the network 192.168.1.0/24, use gateway 192.168.0.3. Then traffic from X to Z will go via Y.

Comment: +1 for your comment. Worked like a charm. Thanks.